How to prevent Express from adding a slash to the route of the URL
I noticed that when I have a route and a sub directory of the same name Express / Nodejs will change the URL when visiting that page in the browser.
For example, if I have a route named foo and then I create a directory in my project named foo the URL changes from, localhost/foo to localhost/foo/.
It is difficult to simply change the directory name or the route.
Is there a way to prevent express from adding the backslash?
Note: when it adds the backslash I'm still able to serve the HTML page but all the references in the page, the CSS, the Javascript, the images, etc all have foo prepended to their path. I can set a base path to fix this but I'd rather fix it on the server side.
server.js:
app.get("/ouput", (request: Request, response: Response, next: any) {
    var url = "ouput.html";
    var options = {root: "absolute\path\to\myproject\public"};
    response.sendFile(url, options);
});

Update
Added the following as suggested and it still adds the slash at the end.
app.use(express.static("output", { redirect: false }));
app.use(express.static("./output", { redirect: false }));
app.use(express.static("public/output", { redirect: false }));
app.use(express.static("./public/output", { redirect: false }));


Express does nothing like that. Post a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Marc If the directory is there the path updates from http://localhost:3000/output?post=123 to http://localhost:3000/output/?post=123. If the directory is not there the URL stays the same.

Perhaps mention that you talk about folders in the filesystem that you serve via express.static(...) and not routes that you define with app.get(...)...

By default express.static does a redirect to the static folder which matches with the requested route. This trailing "/" is the destination for this redirect. This behaviour can be disabled by the option redirect, as below.
app.use(express.static('public', { redirect: false }));

A necessary workaround:
As we know, url(s) once visited will be stored in Browsers as its browsing data. It will then be used to facilitate subsequent browsing. This has an adverse impact in this case.
A url once redirected and prefixed with "/", will incidentally be set in place of the same url without "/". This is the reason though the server has configured to not to redirect, still the url appears as redirected. However the server is functioning correctly. This is only a browser level action.
A manual fix to this issue known from the Internet is to clear the Browsing data. Once the "/" prefixed url is cleared from the data, and the server will redirect no more, this manual fix may be enough for this case. I have tried this and found it working so in Google Chrome and Opera Browsers. Still it is recommended for you to try the same in your secondary browser to mitigate any kind of risks.
While deleting browsing data option, it may not be required to delete data in all categories, still I did not do a test on it to find out the exact option to use.
One last but not least point to take care is that, the moment we see the url appeared redirected even after the server configured not to do so, then this the time we will delete the browsing data. This is correct, we can go ahead and delete. However we also need to remove the trailing "/" from the url presently we see in the browser as well. If we do not do this, and refreshing the page, then the same story will repeat. And we misunderstand as even the deletion does not work.
Therefore as a final note:
a) Delete browsing data
b) Remove the prefixed "/" from the current address bar
c) Refresh page to see latest
Citation:
Express adds slash at the end of url weirdly

I added this and the URL is still updated. I've added my router code and the what I've tried to the original post.

Hi, Thank you for the feedback. Please see the same answer, I have added a section in it, "A necessary workaround". Please see if it is useful.
